# Write a query to find out which team won the most games

Tags: mysql

In MySQL on the command-line, I am trying to find out which team won the most games. If multiple teams have the same number of wins then I need to display them all along with the number of wins.

I have two relations:

```
Team
+---------+-----------+------+----+
| name    | shortName | abbr | id |
+---------+-----------+------+----+

Game
+---------+--------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| game_id | home_team_id | away_team_id | score_home | score_away |
+---------+--------------+--------------+------------+------------+
```

(*home_team_id* and *away_team_id* are both foreign keys for *Team.id*)

To be honest, I'm pretty lost on this one.
I believe I need to:

- compare score_home with score_away to get wins
- sum the number of wins per team
- find the team_id related to the max number of wins
- find the team name that corresponds to that team_id

And I'm thinking that each of these steps is going to be it's own subquery so here's my best attempt (very wrong):

```
> SELECT t.name
  FROM (SELECT team_id
        FROM (SELECT team_id, SUM(games_won) as wins
              FROM (SELECT home_team_id as team_id, COUNT(*) as games_won                        
                    FROM Game
                    WHERE score_home > score_away

                    UNION

                    SELECT away_team_id as team_id, COUNT(*) as games_won                        
                    FROM Game
                    WHERE score_away > score_home) game
                  )
            )
      )
  INNER JOIN Team t
       ON t.id = game.team_id;
```

Please help. And any explanations would be much appreciated

Comment: Please add sample input and expected output

Comment: Take a look at `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY x LIMIT 1`

Comment: We're not allowed to use limit but I can definitely look at GROUP BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  t1.id                                        AS id,
  IFNULL(home_games.cnt + away_games.cnt, 0)   AS games_won
FROM team t1
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT home_team_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM game
  WHERE score_home > score_away
  GROUP BY home_team_id
) home_games ON home_games.home_team_id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT away_team_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM game
  WHERE score_away > score_home
  GROUP BY away_team_id
) away_games ON away_games.away_team_id = t1.id
ORDER BY games_won DESC
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but this would not also include games a team may have won as the away team instead of the home team right?

Comment: yes you are right, i updated query. But main point is idea how to achieve your desired result.

Comment: This totally worked for me (I just removed the comma after t1.id on line 2). But it's so much simpler than what I was trying to do. Thank You!

Comment: @Kelsi027 you are right, updated. I am glad to help you. Happy codding